# AuditLog Events in EventSourcing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-sourcing

I'm building an dotnet application where I have multiple entities with diverses relationships. But I'm strugling with the content inside my events for save in my eventstore.

In this case I want to have in my events, only the changes that ocurred in my aggregate root. Let's suppose that I have a Customer (aggregate root) with many Addresses, and an user changed one property in an address. In my "CustomerEvent", I want to have only the change that the user did.

How can I do it?

I tried using change tracker from EFCore, using reflection for saving the log from my events.

Comment: what's your persistence layer? sql-server? posgresql? mongodb?

Comment: @MarcoMerola i'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Proper way to do it would be creating new event. You can name it AddressChangedEvent. In that way you clearly reveal business requirements.
But since you probably have CRUD based UI it's hard to detect what changed in order to publish appropriate event. Think about task based UI where user has command to change address or any other set of data. BTW event store is almost perfect audit log.